# Binding functions through nested directives with isolated scope failing in Angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

The 1.4 update seems to have introduced an issue when binding functions in nested directives. I have an example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fQLY0N8BTNs38VC8ikll

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function(){
  this.searchFunction = function(term) {
    console.log('you searched for ' + term);
  }
 });

 app.directive('outerDirective', function(){
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      outer: '&'
    },
    template: '<inner-directive inner="cx.outer(term)"></inner-directive>',
    controller: function(){

    },
    controllerAs: 'cx',
    bindToController: true
  };
});

app.directive('innerDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      inner: '&'
    },
    template: '<a ng-click="cx.execute()">Click</a>',
    controller: function(){
      this.execute = function(){
        this.inner('fred');
      }
    },
    controllerAs: 'cx',
    bindToController: true
  };
});
```

This was working in 1.3 but is there some new way I should do this in 1.4?

Clicking on the link you'll see the following error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'cx' in fred
>       at fn (eval at  (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:13036:15), :2:54)
>       at destination.(anonymous function) [as inner] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:8689:22)
>       at execute (http://run.plnkr.co/zE9xlCQNMBrOZZgi/script.js:35:14)
>       at fn (eval at  (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:13036:15), :2:237)
>       at callback (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:23090:17)
>       at Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:15719:28)
>       at Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:15818:23)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:23095:23)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js:3247:21)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you're experiencing an error because you're not using the `{param: value}` approach to calling the function within the directive. The plunkr also lacks the `cx.outer` function so I'm not sure what we'd expect to see happen.

I've updated your plunkr to demonstrate it working with Angular 1.4 with explicit parameter passing: http://plnkr.co/edit/T7aasD?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks @spikeheap.  What is the reason that passing in this object notation works rather than calling the function normally?